# Database Modeling with UML & XMI export - Keys?

Tags: database-design, modeling, uml

I was creating UML class diagrams using Papyrus eclipse modeling too, and exporting it to XMI and importing it in Erwin. I do get an initial list of classes, attributes and datatypes and relationships from the XMI file imported to Erwin. I can create a local profile in Papyrus and show Keys in "PK", "AK", "FK" stereotypes - however these are not interpreted by Erwin.  I always need to mark the primary, alternate & foreign keys in Erwin from scratch.

What is the standard UML/XMI compliant way to express keys like primary key, alternate key & foreign key - all of which may be composite in UML class diagrams, so that the XMI can contain this information and all modeling tools can interpret this.  Basically I want to know - what is the recommended way to do UML modeling for databases- and how can one shows keys.

I've been researching this a lot. I believe there are various RFPs & white papers but database modeling is not part of the UML 2.x yet. There is something called Common Warehouse Metamodel CWM UML which seems database specific (but how do you create a CWM model?) and a new standard called IMM is still not approved?

Answer (score 0):

As you said I am not sure that there is a standard way to express keys in UML...
It shall depend on the tool suite you use maybe Erwin has defined it s own way but I guess you already check that.